# Interpreting $\exp\left(\frac{s}{\ln x}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{t}{\ln(1-x)}\right)$ as $x^t=(1-x)^s$. What am I missing conceptually?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The family of equations:

$$ e^{\frac{s}{\ln(x)}}=e^{\frac{t}{\ln(1-x)}} $$ $s,t\in\Bbb N$

$x\in\Bbb A(0,1)$

Is a family of polynomial equations in disguise. It can be rewritten as:

$x^t=(1-x)^s.$

Plotting the parameter space for all $s,t$ is equivalent to plotting the zero set of this family of polynomial equations in $(0,1)^2.$

On the one hand, plotting points that satisfy $x^t=(1-x)^s,$ yields points of the form $P(\Bbb A,\Bbb A).$

On the other hand, plotting points that satisfy $e^{\frac{s}{\ln(x)}}=e^{\frac{t}{\ln(1-x)}},$ yields points of the form $P(\Bbb A, y)$

The $y-$coordinates could be numbers in $\Bbb Q,\Bbb T,\Bbb A.$

> If these two representations of the family of algebraic equations are equivalent, why can't I determine the nature of the $y-$coordinate? What am I missing here? Are they actually fundamentally different equations but there's a map between them in the form of algebraic manipulations?

Comment: What do you mean by "plotting points that satisfy $x^t=(1-x)^s$"? Are you letting $x$ vary and plotting the $(s,t)$ that match? But they are not uniquely given.

Comment: I mean, fix $s$ and $t$ and then find the root. Then plug the root back into either equation to get the y-coordinate @HenningMakholm

Comment: x @Ultradark: "Find the root" gives you only one number -- how do you plot that in a two-dimensional square?

Comment: @HenningMakholm you take that root and let's say it's, $x=0.3$. Then plug it back into either equation, so, $(0.3)^t.$ So the coordinate pair in this case would be $(0.3,(0.3)^t)$

Comment: x @Ultradark: Would you also find it remarkable that you get different points if you do the same for $2x=3(x-1)$ and $2x+1=3(x-1)+1$ even though these equations are equivalent to each other?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I guess they are equivalent in the sense that they give the same roots, but different y values. So I guess I understand a little better. So what I did is kept the roots the same but moved their location vertically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean:

Fix positive natural numbers $s,t$. Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be the unique pair such that $0<x<1$ and
$$\begin{align}
y_0 &= x_0^t \\
y_0&= (1-x_0)^s \text{.}
\end{align}$$
Let $(x,y)$ be the unique pair such that $0<x<1$ and
$$\begin{align}
y&=\exp\left(\tfrac{s}{\ln x}\right)\\
y&=\exp\left(\tfrac{t}{\ln (1-x)}\right)\text{.}
\end{align}$$

Then

- $x_0$ and $y_0$ are algebraic,
- $x=x_0$, and
- $y_0=y^{\ln x \ln(1-x)}$,

and your question is

> Is $y$ transcendental?

And the answer appears to be unknown, although I believe it would follow from Schanuel's conjecture since the latter implies
$$\mathbb{Q}(\ln x,\mathrm{e}^{1/\ln x})$$
has transcendence degree $2$ whenever $x$ is algebraic.